# Symbol server vs. including pdb files in package

Tags: nuget, pdb-files

What are the benefits of using a symbol server instead of simply including the pdb files in the nuget package?

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage is that the package size is much smaller. So your restore/disk utilization and potentially deployment are smaller by default.

There is also an automatic matching of the pdb to your dll if you deploy an application without the pdb, where you will have to manually match them otherwise.

For example:
The package developer creates a package with pdb files in it.
The app developer can debug with the pdbs in the package. So far so good.
When the app developer deploys the app, he omits the pdbs (because they are large and not necessary).
Several versions of the app have been deployed.

Now the app developer (or another person using the app) hits a problem in production or on a client machine.

By adding the symbolserver url to visual studio, the symbols are resolved automatically on the target machine and the app developer does not have to bring over the right set of pdbs.